# Regex split by delimeter excluding escaped ones and keep empty strings

Tags: java, regex

I need to split a string using "|" as a delimeter, which can be escaped using preceeding "?", in which case it should not be treated as delimeter.
I also want to keep the empty strings in the result, where there are multiple delimeters following each other with nothing in between - I am actually having problem with this part.

Few examples:

```
aaa|bbb|ccc
Result:
aaa
bbb
ccc

aaa?|bbb|ccc
Result:
aaa?|bbb
ccc

aaa?|bbb||ccc|||ddd
Result:
aaa?bbb
<empty string>
ccc
<empty string>
<empty string>
ddd
```

I am using below regex which splits the string correctly while escaping delimeters, but it discards all the empty strings in case of "||". I am using Pattern/Matcher and Java.

```
([^?\\|]|\\?.)+
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: which can be escaped using preceeding "?" ??.. Are you sure '?' is used for escaping?

Comment: ? has a special meaning in regular expressions and your out put also proves that. it is not escaping

Comment: What I meant is that if "?" precedes the delimiter, then its not treated like the actual delimiter. I.e. "?|" should not be treated as delimiter, while "|" should be. SOrry, might have explained it wrong.

Comment: There is no pattern here. Don't use REGEX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using this `Pattern` with the `String.split` method:

```
String[] input = {"aaa|bbb|ccc", "aaa?|bbb|ccc", "aaa?|bbb||ccc|||ddd"};
for (String s: input) {
    //                                          | negative lookbehind for "?" (escaped)
    //                                          |       | "|" (escaped)
    //                                          |       | 
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s.split("(?<!\\?)\\|")));
}
```

**Output**

```
[aaa, bbb, ccc]
[aaa?|bbb, ccc]
[aaa?|bbb, , ccc, , , ddd]
```

Comment: Though this answer is correct, I don't think its wise to use regex in this case. There is no pattern per se when you look at the input.

Comment: @TheLostMind I would agree this is likely to require a custom parser on the long run, but as such I think there *is* a pattern within the specific/literal scope of the question.